# can BigDL be run in aws EMR?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-emr, bigdl

I am beginner in aws EMR and I need to run BigDL in AWS EMR, is this possible or I have to use this service https://aws.amazon.com/fr/blogs/machine-learning/running-bigdl-deep-learning-for-apache-spark-on-aws/
However, I wanted to create a cluster.
Thanak you in advance.

I need to create cluster spark that uses BigDL, Is this possible with AWS EMR?